# The Cypress App could not be downloaded while running "npm install" for Angular App on Windows

Tags: angular, npm, cypress

Error while running "npm install" for Angular App on Windows
I am behind a corporate proxy and the required proxy is set properly.

Here is the error-

```
npm i
> cypress@6.5.0 postinstall C:\mypath\node_modules\cypress
> node index.js --exec install

Installing Cypress (version: 6.5.0)
× Downloading Cypress
→ Cypress Version: 6.5.0
Unzipping Cypress
Finishing Installation
The Cypress App could not be downloaded.
Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration
Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

----------
URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/6.5.0?platform=win32&arch=x64
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 199.82.243.100:3150
.
.
.
.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@6.5.0 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@6.5.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: have you tried downloading it from the link provided in the error? https://download.cypress.io/desktop/6.5.0?platform=win32&arch=x64 (works fine for me btw)

Comment: @TheFabio, do you mean to download and add it to the project manually?

Comment: not exactly, the error is saying npm cannot download the file from this link. if you can download it, it means your proxy configuration is not being used by npm (but it is by your browser)

Comment: I have not set the system proxies, I have set the npm and git proxies. And downloading from the link on the browser works fine.